# Subquery returns more than 1 row in MySQL where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have error in MySQL procedure, because I am trying to select multiple rows in 'Where' parameter. Whole procedure is working when I put  'Where = param_oid' (oid of dossier table row), but I want to return few rows from dossier (so instead of calling procedure for every oid in dossier that exist in table courrier_concerne_dossier) Anyway - I am trying to find solution.

Is there easy way to fix that?

```
DROP procedure if exists `courrier_envoye_pickdossiers`;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE procedure `courrier_envoye_pickdossiers`(IN param_oid binary(16)) 
BEGIN

    set param_oid = (select oid from courrier_envoye where numero_chrono_ordre = "2632" AND numero_chrono_annee = "2013" limit 1);

    SELECT
    CAST(concat(a.prefixe_numero,a.numero, " - ", a.date_ouverture) AS CHAR) as 'noet',


    a.intitule as 'intitule',

    (select nom from gta_geoptima_data.client as m where a.client_oid = m.oid) as 'no_client',
    (select numero_client_abreviation from gta_geoptima_data.client as m where a.client_oid = m.oid) as 'sigle',
    (select nom from gta_geoptima_data.client as m where a.client_oid = m.oid) as 'nom_raison',
    (select intitule from gta_geoptima_data.direction_interne as m where a.direction_oid = m.oid) as 'service',
    a.date_livraison as 'livraison'
    FROM gta_geoptima_data.dossier as a
    WHERE a.oid = (select dossier_oid from courrier_concerne_dossier where courrier_oid = param_oid);

END$$

 call courrier_envoye_pickdossiers(null);
```

> Subquery returns more than 1 row  0.032 sec

Comment: Well, just tweak the SELECT you use in your WHERE clause so it will always return 1 row. Consider `LIMIT`, `DISTINCT` or .. other logic, depending on how and what data is returned.

Comment: maybe I should use EXISTS?

Answer (score 0):

Changing it to doing joins rather than lots of sub queries:-

```
SELECT
CAST(concat(a.prefixe_numero,a.numero, " - ", a.date_ouverture) AS CHAR) AS 'noet',


a.intitule AS 'intitule',

m.nom AS 'no_client',
m.numero_client_abreviation AS 'sigle',
m.nom  AS 'nom_raison',
n.intitule AS 'service',
a.date_livraison AS 'livraison'
FROM gta_geoptima_data.dossier AS a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT MAX(dossier_oid) AS max_dossier_oid
    FROM courrier_concerne_dossier 
    WHERE courrier_oid = param_oid
) sub1
ON a.oid = sub1.max_dossier_oid
LEFT OUTER JOIN gta_geoptima_data.client m
ON a.client_oid = m.oid
LEFT OUTER JOIN gta_geoptima_data.direction_interne n
ON a.direction_oid = n.oid
```

There is a subquery, and I have just used MAX to get the highest matching dossier_oid. Could use MIN, or LIMIT 1 or anything else to reduce the number to 1. Or not bother and bring back all the matching ones (which you could do in your original SQL by changing `WHERE a.oid = (` to `WHERE a.oid IN (` )